# Needing C# LINQ Help reading XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I've got xml that looks like what I have below.  I can read the title but am having trouble getting to the url of media:content.  Any suggestions?  My non-working c# is below along with the xml.

```
 XNamespace xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
        var names =
            (from data in         XDocument.Load("http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/rss").Descendants("item")
             let xElement = data.Element("title")
             let xElementUrls = data.Element("media")
             where xElement != null
             select new
                        {
                           Title = xElement.Value,
                           Urls = data.Elements(xmlns + "media:group")
                           //MediaGroup = data.Element("media:group")
                        }).ToList();
```

and the XML:

```
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" media="screen" href="/styles/xslt/rss.xslt"?>
    <rss version="2.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
       xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
       xmlns:trackback="http://madskills.com/public/xml/rss/module/trackback/" 
       xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" 
       xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/" 
       xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" 
       xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" 
       xmlns:c9="http://channel9.msdn.com">
    <channel>

    <item>
      <title>Building Windows 8 LOB Apps (Repeat)</title>
        <media:group>
          <media:content url="http://video.ch9.ms/sessions/build/2012/2-104R.mp4" 
             expression="full" duration="0" fileSize="1" type="video/mp4" medium="video"/>
          <media:content url="http://video.ch9.ms/sessions/build/2012/2-104R.wmv" 
             expression="full" duration="0" fileSize="1" type="video/x-ms-wmv" medium="video"/>
        </media:group>
    </item>
    <item>
    <item>
    ...
    </item>
```

- Added this based on L.B.'s suggestion but I can't figure out how to get url's out (it is now returning a list of URL's per item as expected.

  ```
  var items = xDoc.Descendants("item")
      .Where(g => g.Element(media + "group") != null)
      .Select(g => new {
                      Title = g.Element("title").Value,
                      Url = g.Element(media + "group")
                              .Element(media + "content")
                              .Attribute("url").Value
                      })
      .ToList();
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`media` is a namespace alias, not an element.

You need to get the `group` element within the `http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/` namespace:

```
XNamespace m = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/";


let xElementUrls = data.Element(m + "group")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/rss");
XNamespace media = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/";

var items = xDoc.Descendants("item")
            .Where(g => g.Element(media + "group") != null)
            .Select(g => new {
                            Title = g.Element("title").Value,
                            Url = g.Element(media + "group")
                                    .Element(media + "content")
                                    .Attribute("url").Value
                            })
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong namespace...

```
XNamespace xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
```

should be

```
XNamespace xmlns = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/";
```

And you are combining the namespace and element name incorrectly

```
...
Urls = data.Elements(xmlns + "group")
....
```

Comment: I feel like I'm close.  I'm still not getting the multiple urls, just one with L.B's code above.  I've changed it some to have the following and now I get multiple urls but can't seem to pull it apart to get my url string value.